# Python creating list of lists where first item is of length one and the second item is of length n?

Tags: python, list

I'm having an issue creating a list of lists in python. Suppose I have the following list:

```
fruitlist = [('Vendor A', 'Apples'),
('Vendor B', 'Apples'),
('Vendor C', 'Bananas'),
('Vendor A', 'Grapes'),
('Vendor A', 'Bananas'),
('Vendor B', 'Oranges')]
```

What I want to do is create list like this : `[[Vendor A, (Apples, Grapes, Bananas)], [Vendor B, (Apples, Oranges)], [Vendor C, (Bananas)]]`

So basically Vendor, and then their offerings. This is the code I currently have, it basically goes through and pulls out just a list of vendors, then loops through and snags each offering, however, the output is not quite I want.

```
vendors = list(set([x[0] for x in fruitlist]))
# this creates a list of just vendors:
output = [[] for x in range (len(vendors))]
#This creates a list with 3 empty lists inside (one for each vendor) where my output will be housed
    for x in range(0,len(vendors)):
        for y in range(0,len(fruitlist)):
            if fruitlist[y][0] == vendors[x]:
                output[x].append(fruitlist[y][1])
```

The output looks something like this:

```
[['Apples', 'Oranges'], ['Apples', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'], ['Bananas']]
```

So the output is now broken down by vendor, and each vendor's offering is now in its own list, but now I have to figure out how to insert the vendor names in there, and I simply can't. If I include the vendor name in the append portion of the for loop,

```
output[x].append((fruitlist[y][0],fruitlist[y][1]))
```

it repeats the vendor name for each fruit. If I use the insert method, it seems to create a brand new item, and increase the length of the list. I've tried a few things, I've tried googling around but I can't figure out the right phrasing. If anyone could point me to the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Also can anyone explain why when I look up vendors:

```
 ['Vendor B', 'Vendor A', 'Vendor C']
```

It puts "B" ahead of "A"? In my original list A was first, does the set function randomly assign the order?

Comment: set's are _un_ordered. how they are printed depends on what youve put into it and may change. why not use a dictionary vendorname->productlist?

Comment: Try `collections.defaultdict`

Comment: Do you really need a list of lists? A dict of lists may be a better option. If you need the vendors to be in a specific order you can use an OrderedDict, or Python 3.6+

Comment: Yeah it doesn't need to be a list, I haven't really used dicts before, I can try that, ty for the suggestion

Comment: Your question is a sort of XY problem: because you are not familiar with dictionaries you tried to do something, that is much simpler to do with a dictionary, using list of lists, leading to some serious complications.  Other answers addressed this XY side of your question, suggesting the use of dictionaries.  [My answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52375469/2749397) takes your question at its face value and shows a simple way to solve your problem using a list of lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sets are merely collections of elements, there is no order like with lists.

The way I would write this would be to create a dictionary and then, when we convert it to a list, we can sort it to match the input order.

```
fruitlist = [('Vendor A', 'Apples'),
('Vendor B', 'Apples'),
('Vendor C', 'Bananas'),
('Vendor A', 'Grapes'),
('Vendor A', 'Bananas'),
('Vendor B', 'Oranges')]
vendors = {}
for vendor, fruit in fruitlist:
    vendors.setdefault(vendor, []).append(fruit)
ordered_fruitlist_vendors = [t[0] for t in fruitlist]
vendors_list = [[k, tuple(v)] for k,v in vendors.items()]
vendors_list.sort(key=lambda t: ordered_fruitlist_vendors.index(t[0]))
```

which gives `vendors_list` as:

```
[['Vendor A', ('Apples', 'Grapes', 'Bananas')], ['Vendor B', ('Apples', 'Oranges')], ['Vendor C', ('Bananas',)]]
```

---

However I doubt that the conversion of a neat dictionary to this clunky list of 2-element lists with tuples is necessary. Surely you want to be able to retrieve the fruits from a vendor in `O(1)` time with `vendors['Vendor A']` rather than having to iterate over this list which will be `O(n)`? Anyway both methods are options now!

---

*Explanation of `setdefault`.*

The `setdefault` method of a dictionary takes two parameters - a key and a value. If the key is already present in the dictionary, the current value is returned, otherwise the key is created with the value passed into the function and that value is returned.

For example:

```
>>> d = {1:2}
>>> d.setdefault(1,3)
2
>>> d
{1: 2}
>>> d.setdefault(3,4)
4
>>> d
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

So a neat trick that uses this method is to set a key to an empty list (`[]`). Then if we don't already have that key (in our case that vendor has not been seen yet), then an empty list is returned. Otherwise we get a reference to the list which contains all that vendor's fruits that we have seen so far. The beauty is that we can just add our new fruit to *whatever* is returned and either a new entry for that vendor will be created and the new fruit is appended or if that vendor already exists, we will just append to the previously created list.

This means that we only have to iterate over the `fruitlist` once so the solution is efficient.

---

One more example of the method in action with lists:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.setdefault(1, []).append(2)
>>> d
{1: [2]}
>>> d.setdefault(1, []).append(3)
>>> d.setdefault(1, []).append(4)
>>> d
{1: [2, 3, 4]}
>>> d.setdefault(2, []).append(3)
>>> d.setdefault(2, []).append(3)
>>> d.setdefault(2, []).append(3)
>>> d
{1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [3, 3, 3]}
```

Comment: Hi Joe, I'm a bit of a newb to Python can you try and explain what's going in your code? I'm a bit confused. So with your first line you create an empty dictionary then you then populate. The second line of your forloop has me a bit confused, are you mapping vendor to an empty list? Also will this not create dupes? Your code works, as I just tried it, but I'm not quite sure how your mapping works here

Comment: @JedBartlet No problem, always happy to help! Please accept though.

Comment: @JoeIddon: Note that using `collections.defaultdict(list)` would avoid the ugliness of `setdefault` (`vendors[vendor].append(fruit)` just looks nicer), and actually run faster in most cases (`setdefault` has to construct the empty `list` every time, even when the key exists; `defaultdict` is lazy, and only constructs a new `list` when the key turns out to be missing).

Comment: @Joe Iddon. Mind. Blown. That is such an elegant solution, wow. This is incredible.  Is there, like a repository of such elegant answers to simple questions, I mean I love seeing stuff like this, it's so clever!

Comment: Imo this is overly complex for a solution that can be done in one loop, just my 2 cents

Answer (score 1):

(*look ma, no dictionaries*)

The data

```
In [15]: fruitlist = [('Vendor A', 'Apples'),
    ...:              ('Vendor B', 'Apples'),
    ...:              ('Vendor C', 'Bananas'),
    ...:              ('Vendor A', 'Grapes'),
    ...:              ('Vendor A', 'Bananas'),
    ...:              ('Vendor B', 'Oranges')]
```

The output list, initially empty

```
In [16]: output = []
```

We are going to use an uncommon capability of a Python's `for` loop, that is the `else` clause.  The body of the `else` clause is executed if the `for` body ended normally, that is without a `break`

```
In [17]: for vendor, fruit in fruitlist:
    ...:     for sublist in output:
    ...:         if sublist[0] == vendor:
    ...:             sublist[1].append(fruit)
    ...:             break
    ...:     else:
    ...:         output.append([vendor, [fruit]])
```

Eventually we check our result

```
In [18]: output
Out[18]: 
[['Vendor A', ['Apples', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']],
 ['Vendor B', ['Apples', 'Oranges']],
 ['Vendor C', ['Bananas']]]
```

I have to say that the original question mentioned sublist where the second element is a tuple, while I have a list, but tuples are immutable...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `for` loop and a `dictionary` no need to overcomplicate it

```
fruits = [ 
    ('Vendor A', 'Apples'),
    ('Vendor B', 'Apples'),
    ('Vendor C', 'Bananas'),
    ('Vendor A', 'Grapes'),
    ('Vendor A', 'Bananas'),
    ('Vendor B', 'Oranges')
]

dicta = {}

for vendor, item in fruits:
    if vendor not in dicta:
        dicta[vendor] = [item]
    else:
        dicta[vendor].append(item)

print(dicta)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 fruits.py
> {'Vendor A': ['Apples', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'], 'Vendor B': ['Apples', 'Oranges'], 'Vendor C': ['Bananas']}
> ```

Comment: vash, when I try using the append method along with a dict I keep getting an error saying tuple ojbect has no attribute append. 


vendors ={'Vendor A': 'Apple'} | 

vendors['Vendor A'].append('Banana')

That code for instance, produces an error saying tuple object has no attribute append

Comment: Its the way you are attempting to use append, for instance I'm calling `dicta[vendor]` which is a `value` and that `value` is a `list` so I'm just appending a list, you cannot append to a dictionary

Comment: In this `dicta[vendor]`, lets say in the loop its representing `dicta['Vendor A']` that returns the `value` of `dicta['Vendor A']` which is a `list` containing `['Apples']` since we are now referring to a `list` we can use `dicta['Vendor A'].append('Grapes')`

Comment: If the `value` is not a `list` you won't be able to `append` to it, in the example you sent me `vendors ={'Vendor A': 'Apple'}` you see the `value` is just a `string` you cannot `append` to a string

Comment: ahhh gotcha, my bad, silly error. Thank you very much, this was a good way to learn more about dicts.

Comment: @JedBartlet Yes spend a lot of time getting used to navigating dictionaries and manipulating them it becomes very useful! Cheers :)